# Disable Autofocus while hovering over Combobox

Tags: winforms, combobox, mousehover

Is it possible to disable the autofocus, when hovering over (MouseHover) a Winforms Combobox? I would like to activate/focus the control after clicking (MouseDown) the control.

Comment: Add a new class, inherit ComboBox, override WndProc, and add this line: `if (m.Msg != 0x200) base.WndProc(ref m);`. Build, drop an instance, run, hover over the control, see if that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static void Combo_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (!cmb.DroppedDown)
            {
                ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.